# How Do I get lean modal js to show more than one modal in wordpress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, modal-dialog, advanced-custom-fields

I have set up the modal for a team member page in WordPress as an advanced custom fields repeater field. That part works well, as it repeats and the modal opens up, but it only has the first team member's modal open up even though, it's another team member. My code is as follows:

```
           <div class="leadership-row">
                <?php 
                    if ( get_field('leadership_block') ):
                    while( has_sub_field('leadership_block') ) :
                ?>
                <div class="Leadership">
                    <a href="#teammember" rel="leanModal">
                    <div class="leadership-image">
                        <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('leadership_image'); ?>" />
                    </div><!-- end of leadership-image -->
                    </a>
                    <div class="leadership-copy">
                        <h5 class="leadership-name"><?php echo get_sub_field('leadership_name'); ?></h5>
                        <h5 class="leadership-position"><?php echo get_sub_field('leadership_position'); ?></h5>
                    </div>
                </div><!-- end of Leadership -->
                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                ?>  
                <?php 
                    if ( get_field('team_modal') ):
                    while( has_sub_field('team_modal') ) :
                ?>
                    <div id="teammember">
                        <a class="modal_close"></a>
                        <div class="modal-image">
                            <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('modal_image'); ?>" />
                        </div><!-- end of modal-image -->
                        <div class="modal-copy">
                            <h4><?php echo get_sub_field('modal_name'); ?></h4>
                            <p><?php echo get_sub_field('modal_position'); ?></p>
                            <img src="<?php echo get_sub_field('modal_icon'); ?>" />
                            <p><?php echo get_sub_field('modal_description'); ?></p>
                        </div><!-- end of modal-copy -->
                    </div><!-- end of teammember -->
                <?php 
                    endwhile;
                    endif;
                ?>
             </div>
```

My JQuery is set up like this:

```
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$("a[rel*=leanModal]").leanModal({ top : 200, overlay : 0.4, closeButton: ".modal_close" });


});
```

Any help would be immensely appreciated.

Comment: I usually run through a count in those cases.

Comment: Here's a loose example: https://gist.github.com/aibrean/09387dc5b265120735a6